# javascript - open link in the tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am quite new to javascript so probably this is not a very smart question - I'd be super thankful for your help

I have the following code:

```
$tp_baraja.find("li").click(function(){
        document.location=tp_questions[tp_pointer].selflink;
        return false;
});
```

Whereby the document link is provided from a database via php if that makes any sense.

Currently this opens in the same window but I want to force it to open in a new tab. How would I do that?

Comment: It's better to add `a` inside of `li` and use `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Your using a LI element, so this does not have a target attribute.. You can either use a inner anchor in each LI or have JS open the URL with a window.open... BUT i would suggest using a anchor as you might trigger a few spam/popup blockers by using window.open.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function openInNewTab(url) {
  $('<a>').attr('href', url).attr('target', '_blank')[0].click();
}
openInNewTab(tp_questions[tp_pointer].selflink);
```

Problem is most browsers have a default setting to prevent pop ups and this they consider pop up so you will see (at least in Chrome)  message that a pop up was prevented

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$tp_baraja.find("li").click(function(){
    window.open(tp_questions[tp_pointer].selflink, '_blank', 'width=600,height=400,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tp_baraja.find("li").click(function(){
    window.open(tp_questions[tp_pointer].selflink,'_blank');
    return false;
});
```

Hope this will help you